# pgfkey to set anchor for negative values in a bar chart

Tags: nodes, pgfkeys, bar-chart

I have a ybar chart with positive and negative bars and "node near coords". I'd like to have the nodes of pos. bars at the top and nodes of neg. bars at the bottom/under the bar. With the following if-case I'm able to address the neg. ones, but I can't find the correct pgfkey or whatever to change the anchor in order to get a bottom position.
I hope, you could come up with a simple solution.
Many thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,lipsum}  
\usepackage{tikz}  

\pgfplotsset{%  
  /pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={  
   /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%  
     \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,bar width=6pt,yshift=-0.14cm,bar shift=0pt]  
     plot coordinates {(0cm,0.35cm)};}  
  }}  
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}  

\begin{document}  

\begin{figure}[H]  
    \centering  
 \begin{tikzpicture}  
  \centering  
  \begin{axis}[small,ybar,   
        height=7.2cm, width=14.5cm,bar width=0.35cm,  
        scaled ticks=false,  
        y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed   zerofill,precision=3,/tikz/.cd},  
        ymin=-0.016, ymax=0.056,ymajorgrids,tick align=inside,axis y line=left,  
        ylabel={[dimless]},  
        xtick=data,enlarge x limits=0.25,axis x line*=bottom,major x tick style = transparent,  
        symbolic x coords={$A$,$B$,$C$},  
        every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90,anchor=west, font=\scriptsize, xshift=-3pt, yshift=0pt},  
            nodes near coords={%  
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}%  
        \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotspointmeta<0}%  
        \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%  
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%  
        \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=1pt  
             \pgfkey{anchor={east}} % <<<<<<<<<<<<< What's the right pgfkey to set the anchor?  
        \else   
            \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3,print sign]{\pgfplotspointmeta}       
        \fi  
        },  
        legend style={draw=none,draw opacity=0, at={(0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north, legend columns=5, transpose legend, font=\small,  
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.15cm}}  
    ]  
    \addplot [draw=none, fill=red] coordinates {  
      ($A$,-0.012)  
      ($B$,+0.000)   
      ($C$,+0.024) };  
   \legend{ABC}  
  \end{axis}  
  \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{figure}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were looking for the `nodes near coords align` parameter. I enclose an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgfplots,lipsum}  
\usepackage{tikz}  

\pgfplotsset{%  
  /pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={  
   /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%  
     \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,bar width=6pt,yshift=-0.14cm,bar shift=0pt]  
     plot coordinates {(0cm,0.35cm)};}  
  }}  
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}  

\begin{document}  

\begin{figure}[H]  
    \centering  
 \begin{tikzpicture}  
  \centering  
  \begin{axis}[small,ybar,   
        height=7.2cm, width=14.5cm,bar width=0.35cm,  
        scaled ticks=false,  
        y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed   zerofill,precision=3,/tikz/.cd},  
        ymin=-0.016, ymax=0.056,ymajorgrids,tick align=inside,axis y line=left,  
        ylabel={[dimless]},  
        xtick=data,enlarge x limits=0.25,axis x line*=bottom,major x tick style = transparent,  
        symbolic x coords={$A$,$B$,$C$},  
        nodes near coords align={horizontal},
        every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, 
 font=\scriptsize, xshift=-3pt, yshift=0pt},  
            nodes near coords={%  
            \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=3,print sign]{\pgfplotspointmeta}       
        },  
        legend style={draw=none,draw opacity=0, at={(0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north, legend columns=5, transpose legend, font=\small,  
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.15cm}}  
    ]  
    \addplot [draw=none, fill=red] coordinates {  
      ($A$,-0.012)  
      ($B$,+0.000)   
      ($C$,+0.024) };  
   \legend{ABC}  
  \end{axis}  
  \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{figure}  

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]